# Why is the toolbar not displayed in the next window (tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter

When you click the (DB Access) button in the main menu, the following dialog box opens (class DB_control) with a table from the database.

However, the table is displayed, but the toolbar to it is not displayed. Although the pack method did, or did I forget to specify some other parameter?

I tried to enter width and  height for toolbarTop (for tk.Frame), but it didn't give anything either

```
class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,root):
        super ().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
        
    def init_main(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame (bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.X)
        self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='IcAdd.gif')  
        btn_open_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, command=self.open_dialog, bg='#d7d8e0', bd=5, compound=tk.TOP, image=self.add_img)
        btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)
        Tooltip(btn_open_dialog, 'DB Access', delay=0,duration=1500)

        self.create_pass_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='IcSearch.gif')
        btn_create_pass_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, bg='#d7d8e0', bd=5, compound=tk.TOP, command=self.open_dialog,image=self.create_pass_img)
        btn_create_pass_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)
        Tooltip(btn_create_pass_dialog, 'Create', delay=0, duration=1500)

        self.clouse_main_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='IcEdit.gif')
        btn_close_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, compound=tk.TOP, command = self.destroy,image=self.clouse_main_img)
        btn_close_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)
        Tooltip(btn_close_dialog, 'Cl', delay=0, duration=1500)

    def tooltip_on(self):
        Tooltip()

    def open_dialog(self):
        DB_control()

class DB_control(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_second()
        self.db = db
        self.view_records()
        self.view = app 

    def init_second(self):
        toolbarTOP = tk.Frame (bg='#a7aeeb', bd=100)
        toolbarTOP.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.title ('База данных IRMASH')
        self.geometry('500x300+500+350')
        self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='')
        btn_open_dialog_third = tk.Button(toolbarTOP, command=self.open_dialog_third,bg='#d7d8e0',bd=0, compound=tk.TOP,image=self.add_img)
        btn_open_dialog_third.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)
        Tooltip(btn_open_dialog_third, 'Add', delay=0, duration=1500

        self.update_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='')
        btn_edit_dialog = tk.Button(toolbarTOP,bg='#d7d8e0',bd=0, compound=tk.TOP,command=self.open_update_dialog, image=self.update_img)
        btn_edit_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=10)
        Tooltip(btn_edit_dialog, 'Edit', delay=0, duration=1500)

        self.delete_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='IcDelete.gif')
        btn_delete = tk.Button(toolbarTOP,bg='#d7d8e0',bd=0, compound=tk.TOP,command=self.open_delete_dialog, image=self.delete_img)
        btn_delete.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=10)
        Tooltip(btn_delete, 'Delite', delay=0, duration=1500)

        self.search_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='IcSearch.gif')
        btn_search = tk.Button(toolbarTOP,bg='#d7d8e0',bd=0, compound=tk.TOP,command=self.open_search_dialog, image=self.search_img)
        btn_search.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=10)
        Tooltip(btn_search, 'Search', delay=0, duration=1500)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self,columns = ('id', 'name_of_product'), height=20,show='headings')
        self.tree.column('id', width=30, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('name_of_product', width=180, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('id', text = '№')
        self.tree.heading('name_of_product', text='Name')
        self.tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        scroll=tk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.tree.yview)
        scroll.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() 
    db = DB()  
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.title ("NoneName")
    root.geometry("300x89+100+100")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nope, It seems to me I have found my problem: I tryed to use in class DB_control(tk.Toplevel) and then for toolbar I used tk.Frame and that why it didn't show at all.

Comment: If I use tk.Toplevel for the toolbar again, it will open in the third window, and I need both the table and the toolbar to be in the same window.

Comment: You need to pass `self` as the first argument when creating the toolbar frame: `toolbarTOP = tk.Frame(self, ...)`.

Comment: O yes! it really works, thanks, I tryed the same but with self.tk)